# Prove : if $A\triangle B\subseteq D$ and $B\triangle C\subseteq D$, then $A\triangle C\subseteq D$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C,D$ sets.
Prove that if $A\triangle B\subseteq D$ and $B\triangle C\subseteq D$, then $A\triangle C\subseteq D$. 
$$A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$$
$$(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\subseteq D$$
$$B\triangle C=(B\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus B)$$
$$(B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)\subseteq D$$
$$(A\cup C)\setminus (A\cap B)\cup (B\cap C)$$
$$(A\cup C)\setminus B\cap (A\cup C)\subseteq D \qquad (*)$$
$$A\cup C \subseteq D \qquad (**)$$
$$A\triangle C\subseteq D$$

I'm not sure about the parts $(*)$ and $(**)$? And if my proof is good enough. There is a better way?

Comment: You seem to be implying that the hypotheses should imply that $A\cup C\subseteq D$ which is not necessarily true.  Consider the case where $A=B=C=\{1\}$ and $D=\emptyset$.  You would have that $A\triangle B = A\triangle C=B\triangle C = \emptyset \subseteq D$ but $A\cup C = \{1\}$ is not a subset of $D$

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a proof. You write down the definition, but you do not give any explaination.

We want to show $A\Delta C\subseteq D$

So let $x\in A\Delta C$. Then $x\in (A\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus A)$.

So $x\in A\setminus C$ or $x\in C\setminus A$.
Suppose $x\in A\setminus C$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$.

Since $A\Delta B\subseteq D$ and $B\Delta C\subseteq D$, we have:

$(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\subseteq D$

and

$(B\setminus C)\cup (C\setminus B)\subseteq D$.

If $x\in B$, then $x\in B\setminus C$. So $x\in D$.

If $x\notin B$, then $x\in A\setminus B$. So $x\in D$.

Keep in mind, that we have $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$.

The other case: $x\notin A$ and $x\in C$ functions analogously.